# uniqueN returns wrong results with conditions in j

Tags: r, data.table

Given a dataset like this:

```
 test =data.table(
  id = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "e", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t"),
  int=c(NA, NA, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, NA, 5, NA, 6, 7, NA, 8, NA, 8, 10))
```

i want to count the number of unique ids where int has specific values:

```
test[, .(three=uniqueN(id[int==3]), zero=uniqueN(id[int==0]), missing= uniqueN(id[is.na(int)]))]
```

the result

```
   three zero missing
1:     3    3       6
```

is obviously wrong: there are only 2 ids for which int is 0 or 3. the correct result should look like this:

```
   three zero missing
1:     2    2       6
```

What is wrong with this approach?
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are `NA` elements in `int`, which needs to be taken care of i.e. `==` with `NA` returns `NA`.  Either use `%in%` or create a second condition with `&` with `!is.na` i.e. the value is not an `NA` so that the `NA` elements return `FALSE` instead of `NA`

```
test[, .(three = uniqueN(id[int == 3 & !is.na(int)]), 
         zero=uniqueN(id[int %in% 0]))]
#    three zero
#1:     2    2
```

---

Or another option is to make use of `na.rm` in `uniqueN` which is by default `FALSE`, therefore, it counts the `NA` as another unique value

```
test[, .(three=uniqueN(id[int==3], na.rm = TRUE), 
       zero=uniqueN(id[int==0], na.rm = TRUE),
       missing= uniqueN(id[is.na(int)]))]
#   three zero missing
#1:     2    2       6
```

---

Or yet another way is to first take care of `NA` with `na.omit` or `complete.cases` then use the OP's code

```
na.omit(test)[, .(three = uniqueN(id[int == 3]),
      zero = uniqueN(id[int == 0]))]
#    three zero
#1:     2    2
```

---

By doing the `==` without taking `NA` into account, it returns `NA` instead of `FALSE` and this will return the `NA` while subsetting as well

```
c(NA, 3) == 3
#[1]   NA TRUE

c(5, 4)[c(NA, 3) == 3]
#[1] NA  4
```

whereas

```
c(NA, 3) == 3 & !is.na(c(NA, 3))
#[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Or with `%in%`

```
c(NA, 3) %in% 3
#[1] FALSE  TRUE
```